# C++ application can not find shared libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, docker, unix, cmake

I have the cross-platfrom c++ application that build using cmake and vcpkg. I use visual studio and everything is ok in windows. I try to compile and run my application inside docker container with ubuntu 18.04 and oneAPI. My application is succesfully compiled but after running I get some errors with shared libraries.

```
/home/rlnn/.vs/rlnnsimplatform/out/build/x64-linux-gcc-debug/main: error while loading shared libraries: libtbb.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So my application can not find oneTBB shared libs.

I use `ldd -d main` to obtain the list of shared libraries need for my application.

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffb77f2000)
        libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.4.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1 (0x00007f0b25c33000)
        libmkl_core.so.1 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.4.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so.1 (0x00007f0b217c5000)
        libmkl_tbb_thread.so.1 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.4.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_tbb_thread.so.1 (0x00007f0b1f461000)
        libtbb_debug.so.12 => /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8/libtbb_debug.so.12 (0x00007f0b1f1bd000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0b1edb0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0b1ea12000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0b1e7f3000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0b1e5db000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0b1e1ea000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0b274ff000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0b1dfe6000)
        libtbb.so.12 => /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8/libtbb.so.12 (0x00007f0b1dd6e000)
```

It seems that all shared libraries's paths are resolved.

I tried to add oneapi paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it did not help

```
rlnn@16a54760cac8:~/.vs/rlnnsimplatform/out/build/x64-linux-gcc-debug$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8
```

All tbb libs are really located in  `/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8`

```
rlnn@16a54760cac8:/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8$ cd /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8 && ls
libtbb.so             libtbbbind.so.3.4            libtbbbind_2_5.so.3          libtbbmalloc.so            libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2.4
libtbb.so.12          libtbbbind_2_0.so            libtbbbind_2_5.so.3.4        libtbbmalloc.so.2          libtbbmalloc_proxy_debug.so
libtbb.so.12.4        libtbbbind_2_0.so.3          libtbbbind_2_5_debug.so      libtbbmalloc.so.2.4        libtbbmalloc_proxy_debug.so.2
libtbb_debug.so       libtbbbind_2_0.so.3.4        libtbbbind_2_5_debug.so.3    libtbbmalloc_debug.so      libtbbmalloc_proxy_debug.so.2.4
libtbb_debug.so.12    libtbbbind_2_0_debug.so      libtbbbind_2_5_debug.so.3.4  libtbbmalloc_debug.so.2
libtbb_debug.so.12.4  libtbbbind_2_0_debug.so.3    libtbbbind_debug.so          libtbbmalloc_debug.so.2.4
libtbbbind.so         libtbbbind_2_0_debug.so.3.4  libtbbbind_debug.so.3        libtbbmalloc_proxy.so
libtbbbind.so.3       libtbbbind_2_5.so            libtbbbind_debug.so.3.4      libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2
```

My Dockerfile content

```
# base image from docker hub with oneAPI based on ubuntu
FROM intel/oneapi-basekit:2021.4-devel-ubuntu18.04
LABEL description="Container for use with Visual Studio"

RUN apt-get update \
  && echo 'y' | apt-get install software-properties-common \
  && add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test \
  && echo 'y' | apt-get install gcc-10 g++-10 \
  && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 100 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-10

#install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo rsync zip openssh-server make git unzip tar curl ninja-build gdb gfortran zlib1g-dev libboost-all-dev

# configure SSH for communication with Visual Studio 
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \ 
   ssh-keygen -A 

#install vcpkg for c++ dependencies management using vcpkg.json
RUN useradd -m -d /home/rlnn -s /bin/bash -G sudo rlnn && echo 'rlnn:12345' | chpasswd \
  && cd /home/rlnn \
  && git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git \
  && ./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh \
  && chown -R rlnn /home/rlnn/vcpkg

#ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

RUN sudo groupadd docker && sudo usermod -aG docker rlnn
   
RUN cd /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/intel64/gcc4.8 \ 
  && sudo cp libtbb.so.12 /usr/lib/libtbb.so.12

# expose port 22 
EXPOSE 22
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check this : https://github.com/TaliaferroLab/LABRAT/issues/3, it seems as actual problem, fixed by downgrading to earlier version

Comment: Even someone just copied certain dlls into /usr/lib and suddenly it start working which.. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=694416

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]; for example, the Dockerfile you're using to construct the build image?

Comment: @SamuelB. I copied libtbb.so.12 to /usr/lib/libtbb.so.12 and my application run succesfully so all libraries were find succesully. Apparently the main problem consists in oneTBB components. I haven’t figured out the real reason yet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I will add it ASAP.